# pandas error bucle

Tags: python, pandas, bucle-for, bucles

Necesito hacer que las filas donde el valor de "C" es mayor que el de "B" se eliminen del `dataframe` una por una, recalculando el valor de "C" cada vez que se borra una fila para pero no he podido.

Este es mi código pero no me ha funcionado lo último. ¿Alguien me podría ayudar u orientar sobre como ejecutarlo?. Gracias de antemano

Dataframe:

```
n   A   B   C
1   6   15  6
5   7   18  13
3   12  22  25
6   4   25  29
4   3   26  32
2   4   30  36
```

Código:

```
t1 = [1, 6, 15]
t2 = [2, 4, 30]
t3 = [3, 12, 22]
t4 = [4, 3, 26]
t5 = [5, 7, 18]
t6 = [6, 4, 25]


df = pd.DataFrame()


df = pd.DataFrame([t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6], columns = ['n','A','B'])

df = df.sort_values(by='B', ascending=True, ignore_index=True)

df['C'] = 0
df.loc[0,'C'] = df.loc[0,'A']


for i in range(1, len(df)):
     df.loc[i, 'C'] = df.loc[i-1, 'C'] + df.loc[i,'A']
```

Para al menos intentar borrar las que no cumplen había usado esta última línea pero me arroja error.

```
for i in range(1, len(df)):
     df.loc[i, 'C'] = df.loc[i-1, 'C'] + df.loc[i,'A']
    if (df.loc[i,'C'] > df.loc[i,'A']):
        df = df.drop([i], inplace=True)
```

El resultado final del dataframe debería ser el siguiente:

```
n   A   B   C
1   6   15  6
5   7   18  13
6   4   25  17
4   3   26  20
2   5   30  25
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Podrías agregar un ejemplo de cómo se debería ver el `dataframe` al final del proceso? No entiendo bien lo que deseas hacer, quieres únicamente reorganizar las filas según una condición? Por otra parte, el título de las preguntas debe ser descriptivo, "pandas error fácil" no hace referencia al error que tienes ni a lo que se desea hacer.

Comment: Hola, gracias por responder, hay 2 opciones. La primera sería en este orden:   n   A   B   C
1   6   15  6
5   7   18  13
6   4  25  17
4   3   26  20
2   5   30  25
3   12   22  25.    Para este caso solo se traslada al final la fila que no cumple. Otra opción sería directamente eliminar la fila que no cumple y recalcular hasta que todas cumplan con la condición de C<= B, lo que yo creo que sería más sencillo. Para este caso, el resultado del df sería el siguiente:                    n   A   B   C
1   6   15  6
5   7   18  13
6   4  25  17
4   3   26  20
2   5   30  25

Comment: Buen día, la información en los comentarios pierde un poco de formato por lo que no se ve bien, es mejor [edit] la pregunta y agregar la información ahí para verla de forma adecuada.

Comment: Disculpa, ya lo he corregido en la pregunta. También reformulé la pregunta para un mejor entendimiento. Gracias

Comment: Una pregunta, no se si es un error de dedo al ingresar el resultado esperado pero ¿Por qué la última fila dice `2 5 30 25`? ¿No debería ser `2 4 30 24`?

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Al utilizar `pandas` es recomendable **no** utilizar ciclos (Por ejemplo `for`) para iterar en los elementos, hay métodos optimizados que trabajan con el `dataset` rápida y eficientemente. En la mayoría de los casos, si lo que quieres hacer crees que se puede hacer con un `for` entonces es el camino incorrecto (O el que va a tardar más y tener mayor impacto al procesador). En esos casos, si no hay un método directo que realice la tarea entonces apply podría ser una buena opción, como último recurso sería utilizar ciclos.

El primer punto, que no es relevante para la respuesta pero te va a ayudar a aprender una mejor forma de calcular `C`, es que los valores de esa columna son la suma acumulada de la columna `A` y por lo tanto se puede obtener simplemente con la función [`pandas.DataFrame.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) de la siguiente forma:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].cumsum()
```

Si imprimimos la columna `C` obtenemos la siguiente serie:

```
0     6
1    13
2    25
3    29
4    32
5    36
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Entendiendo el punto anterior es más fácil saber lo que hay que hacer con tu `dataframe`.

La forma larga de hacerlo, como lo haces actualmente, es calcular `C`, luego eliminar la primera fila donde el valor de `C` es mayor que el valor de `B` y luego recalcular `C`, pero eso hace que necesites procesar el `dataframe` multiples veces. En tu ejemplo al ser 6 filas tal vez no parece tanto, pero si tuvieras miles de filas y tuvieras que repetir el proceso cada vez que encuentres un valor de `C` mayor a un valor de `B` entonces el programa va a consumir muchos recursos y tiempo.

Una mejor forma de hacerlo es analizar el `dataframe` una sola vez, fila por fila y al hacerlo revisar si la suma acumulada de la culumna `A` es mayor al valor de la fila que se esté evaluando en la columna `B`, si es mayor, ignorar esa fila y seguir adelante. Si es menor, entonces devolver la suma acumulada.

Para eso vamos a crear nuestra propia función de suma acumulada y utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) para analizar todo el `dataframe` una sola vez y calcular todos los valores de `C` correctamente.

Como deseamos recordar la suma acumulada cada vez que evaluamos una nueva fila entonces es necesario crear una "función con memoria":

```
def myCumsum(row):
    # Si el valor de la suma acumulada + el valor de la fila actual en la columna "A"
    # es mayor al valor de la fila actual en la columna "B" entonces ignorar la fila
    if myCumsum.sum + row['A'] > row['B']:
        return None
    # En caso contrario agregar el valor de la fila actual en la columna "A" a la suma acumulada
    else:
        myCumsum.sum += row['A']
        return myCumsum.sum
```

**Nota importante:** La función `myCumsum` tiene un atributo `sum` que es el encargado de "recordar" la suma acumulada, pero para que funcione correctamente es necesario inicializar `myCumsum.sum` antes de utilizar la función o devolverá error.

Aplicamos la función anterior al `dataframe` y asignamos el resultado a la columna `C`:

```
df['C'] = df.apply(myCumsum, axis=1)
```

Si imprimimos el `dataframe` obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
   n   A   B     C
0  1   6  15   6.0
1  5   7  18  13.0
2  3  12  22   NaN
3  6   4  25  17.0
4  4   3  26  20.0
5  2   4  30  24.0
```

Es importante notar que la fila que ignoramos ahora tiene un valor `NaN` (Del inglés "Not a Number") y podemos eliminar todas las filas que contengan `NaN` simplemente al utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```
df.dropna(inplace=True)
```

Ejemplo completo:

```
import pandas as pd

t1 = [1, 6, 15]
t2 = [2, 4, 30]
t3 = [3, 12, 22]
t4 = [4, 3, 26]
t5 = [5, 7, 18]
t6 = [6, 4, 25]


df = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.DataFrame([t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6], columns = ['n','A','B'])
df = df.sort_values(by='B', ascending=True, ignore_index=True)

# Función personalizada de suma acumulada
def myCumsum(row):
    # Si el valor de la suma acumulada + el valor de la fila actual en la columna "A"
    # es mayor al valor de la fila actual en la columna "B" entonces ignorar la fila
    if myCumsum.sum + row['A'] > row['B']:
        return None
    # En caso contrario agregar el valor de la fila actual en la columna "A" a la suma acumulada
    else:
        myCumsum.sum += row['A']
        return myCumsum.sum

# Inicializamos el atributo "sum"
myCumsum.sum = 0
# Aplicamos nuestra función de suma acumulada y asignamos el resultado a la columna "C"
df['C'] = df.apply(myCumsum, axis=1)

df.dropna(inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Esto imprime el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
   n  A   B     C
0  1  6  15   6.0
1  5  7  18  13.0
3  6  4  25  17.0
4  4  3  26  20.0
5  2  4  30  24.0
```

**Nota:** Como puse en el comentario, no sé porque en tu pregunta pusiste la última fila con valor de `5` en la columna `A`, los datos originales de la pregunta y que se utilizaron para crear el `dataframe` tienen `4` en esa posición por lo que la suma acumulada para esa fila sería `24` no `25`.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @HeytalePazguato por ayudarme, me ha quedado todo muy claro. Estaré eternamente agradecido. Saludos

Comment: Buen día @user305544, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).